# TIFF to TEXT, or index TIFF files based on text content

Tags: linux, windows, images, tiff

I have a couple thousand Tiff files, each one is a multi-page text document. I would like to be able to search the content of these files and organize/index them based on certain information, such as Name, City, County, State, Street, Zip Code, etc. 
The goal is to find the relevant files based on search terms. For example, if I were to search "Doyle, Bob" AND "Orange County" all files containing these terms would be retrieved.
I have windows and linux PCs available, but it does not have to be cross platform.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

#### I would like to be able to search the content of these (tiff) files.

Two solutions are presented below, for Windows and for Linux.

---

#### Windows Solution

You can install the **TIFF IFilter**.

> Windows® TIFF IFilter enables you to search for TIFF documents based
>   on text content. When loaded, Windows TIFF IFilter performs optical
>   character recognition (OCR) processing of TIFF images, and then it
>   provides the recognized text to the caller to build the search index.
>
> Windows TIFF IFilter focuses on text-based documents, which means that
>   searching will be more successful for documents that contain clearly
>   identifiable text (for example, black text on a white background), and
>   less successful for documents that contain mixed content (for example,
>   artistic text or text inside of pictures). Additionally, low-quality
>   images and mixed languages can negatively impact OCR processing, and
>   consequently, lower the quality of the search results.
>
> Windows TIFF IFilter supports all TIFF documents that are complaint
>   with Adobe TIFF Revision 6.0 specifications, and it includes the most
>   frequent compressions (such as LZW, JPG, CCITT v4, CCITT v6, and
>   uncompressed).

The source link includes detailed installation instructions.

Note:

- Windows TIFF Filter is not available in Windows 7 Starter or Windows 7 Home Basic (according to [Tip: Search Tiff Files in Windows 7 by Enabling Tiff Indexing](http://www.gilsmethod.com/tip-search-tiff-files-windows-7-enabling-tiff-indexing))

Source [Windows TIFF IFilter Installation and Operations Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd755985%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

---

#### Linux Solution

1. Convert the TIFF files to Text files or PDF files.

   - The link belows shows how to convert to PDF with an intermediate OCR step (that uses Tesseract).
   - The intermediate step produces a Text file.
   - This means that the PDF is created from text not images.
2. Search the Text files or the PDF files as you wish.

See [Scanning and editing text with OCR](https://www.ubuntu-user.com/Magazine/Archive/2013/18/Scanning-and-editing-text-with-OCR) for one approach for the conversion.

Comment: PDF can contain images, and usually TIFF converted to PDF includes only the image of files (non OCR converter).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The link I quoted solves that problem by using an intermediate OCR step using Tesseract ;) I will clarify the answer.

Comment: Does that Tesseract conversion mean that the PDF contains the TIFF, or does it convert the embedded image format?